# Angular2 ngFor select doesn't update until model changes

Tags: service, angular

I have a simple select with an ngFor and the select box is empty until I type into one of the other fields and then it magically shows the data even though I know it completed the data call previously.

My view

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="payerId">PayerId</label>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="#item of model.payers">{{item.HealthPlanName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="providerType">Provider Type</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.providerType"/>
</div>
```

My Component

```
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit, View} from "angular2/core";
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgForm, NgFormControl, NgFor} from "angular2/common";
import {CoverageService} from "../../services/coverage/coverage.services";
import "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
    selector: "coverage",
    providers: [CoverageService]
})
@View({
    templateUrl: "/Scripts/appScripts/components/coverage/coverage.html",
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgForm, NgFormControl, NgFor, PayerSelector]
})
export class CoverageComponent implements OnInit {
    model = new CoverageRequest();
    constructor(private coverageService: CoverageService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPayers();
    }
    getPayers() {
        this.coverageService.getPayers()
            .subscribe(resp => {
                this.model.payers = resp;
            });
    }  
}
```

Really scratching my head.

Here are the libraries I am using:

```
"dependencies": {
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
"systemjs": "^0.19.20",
"es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
"es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
"zone.js": "0.5.10"
}
```

My Service

```
import {Http, Response} from "angular2/http";
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {COVERAGE_BASE} from "../../config";
import "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class CoverageService {
    constructor(public http: Http) {

    }

    getPayers(): any {
        return this.http.get(COVERAGE_BASE + "/Payers")
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

Data

```
[{
    "Id": 3817,
    "ProviderId": 2,
    "ApiPayerId": "00028",
    "HealthPlanName": "Georgia Medicaid",
    "Type": null,
    "PayerSynonyms": null
}, {
    "Id": 3818,
    "ProviderId": 2,
    "ApiPayerId": "00143",
    "HealthPlanName": "J. F. Molloy and Associates Inc.",
    "Type": null,
    "PayerSynonyms": null
}]
```

Comment: why you have used `this.model.payers` instead of `this.model` simply ? one thing more before funcction call your `this.model.payers` is empty or not ?

Comment: Try `<option *ngFor="#item of model.payers | async">` and `getPayers() {
        this.model.payers = this.coverageService.getPayers();
}`

Comment: this.model is an object that contains a list of payers and many other properties.

Comment: @ewahner i have created one plnkr for your problem please put your code here. this works fine. but still if you have any problem update the plnkr with your code where you fail....ill solve your problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/uG4rfXySQYWHzlj6iIuj?p=preview

Comment: Your code works fine but it is not an Observable.  I also used just a static list of objects and that worked just fine.  Only when I plugged in an Http call that returns an Observable did it start behaving this way.

Comment: I also created a plunkr to try to reproduce your problem with a raw observable: https://plnkr.co/edit/2tus6ZZzrAiAvdRqhsMQ?p=preview. But I can't reproduce :-(

Comment: I tried the `| async` and it behaves the same way.

Comment: Right now its not but you can change it to be an `Observable` of any type of object you want like `Observable<Payer[]>` , what's your service's method code and the response data you are testing with?

Comment: I updated with versions of libraries and my service code.  The service works...I can see that it is getting hit and retrieving data, its just the select box has nothing in it until I start typing in one of the other fields.

Comment: what does 
    model = new CoverageRequest();
do ?

Comment: Can you show the structure of the data you are getting?

Comment: I removed the new CoverageRequest() as I don't even need it right now.  So its just a form with a simple `select`.  Now what I am seeing is that if I click the select box...with nothing in it and then click anywhere else so the "onBlur" is probably firing...all of a sudden the select box is filled and this is well after the service method had returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try initiating the model in ngOnInit instead of directly in the class. You will need to use the elvis operator in the view, because the model initially will be undefined. Read more about the elvis operator here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#sts=The%20Elvis%20operator%20(%20%3F.%20)%20and%20null%20property%20paths

I am not entirely sure but i think it should work.

Comment: That was already suggested in an answer that was down-voted and ultimately deleted.  I had tried that and the same occurred.

Comment: Oh well. I will let my answer stay here so nobody else will answer it a third time then :P